# Get build size of project on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have integrated Jenkins pipelines with Veracode platform. I have one issue that I have to deploy package to Veracode, only packages which size of package less than 1MB. I would like to know how can I get build size of project with Jenkins script?

```
 stage ('VeraCode Upload and Scan') {
        steps {
            script{
                if(buildSize<=1MB){
                    deployProjectJarToVeracode();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need some information, what platform is the build running on? linux?

Comment: Yes on Linux server.

Comment: Can anyone help to me for this issue please?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly look at how to get the size of a file on linux.

```
stat ${fileName} | awk '{ print $9 }'
```

Running this command will return the number of bytes of the file.

Then you just need to check whether it is larger than 1Mb or not in Jenkins, so you can probably do something like this...

```
script {
    size = sh "stat ${fileName} | awk '{ print $9 }'"
    mb = 1024 * 1024
    if (size <= mb) {
        deployProjectJarToVeracode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution gave me good idea about how to get filename and size